# how to store registered and guest session login in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flash, session

i have a highscore system in that i have small doubt like i want to store the user session in the mysql table and also the guest session. like if the user is registered user then that session should be stored in the mysql db. else if the user is not registered i.e guest user then also i need to store with the guest account for my high score system for a flash games site. how to achieve this please provide a small example....

Comment: are you already have a mechanism for registered users? if so then work with guests like with registered users, like guest1242345

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sessions to be saved into the database with code as on the PHP manual page: [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).